# Form stuck at initialization

Tags: vb.net, client-server

I built a server - client program.
When the clinet connect to the server , the server return value "1" string to the client.
At this point the client has to close Form1 and open Form2.
Form2 is loaded but stack in infinity loop.
I tried to push the program to see if the debugger show me where it stack but nothing.

```
 Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf getMessage)
 ctThread.Start()

Private Sub getMessage()

        For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
            Try
                infiniteCounter = 1
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
                Dim inStream(1024) As Byte
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
                returndata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream)
                returndata = returndata.Substring(0, returndata.IndexOf("$"))
                serverStream.Flush()
                If returndata <> "" Then

                    If Form2.InvokeRequired Then
                        Form2.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf doOrder))
                    Else
                        doOrder()
                    End If
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        Next

    End Sub

    
    Sub doOrder()

        Dim order As String = Strings.Left(returndata, 1)
        Select Case order
            Case 0
                MsgBox("User with that nick allready exist")
            Case 1
                Form2.Show()
                Form2.Text = Form1.Text3.Text
                Form1.Close()
            Case 2
                Form2.List1.Items.Add(Strings.Right(returndata, Len(returndata) - 1))
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking, but I will note the infinite loop could be clearer if you replaced the `For` loop and `inifiniteCounter` simply with `Do Until 1 = 2` and `Loop` where the `Next` is. That should give you an infinite loop with no variables.

Comment: Note that `Dim inStream(1024) As Byte` creates an array of 1025 bytes, in case that messes things up in the code.

Comment: You should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). It could be that it will point out some problem that is causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Try `Dim bytesRead As Integer = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)` and `Dim returnData as String =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead)`. Also ensure that you've enabled [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Ok
The problem was solved when I moved the code with the client thread from the module to the form code.